# Position text in lower right corner of a HTML label in Layout

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layouts, html, css

I have a problem with QGIS 3.32.x, where I cannot vertically align HTML labels in Layouts anymore.

The following HTML is perfectly aligned in QGIS 3.30, but refuses to align in QGIS 3.32.x:

```html
<div style="position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;margin:10;background-color:red">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

[image]

I have already reported this issue as a bug (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54418), but  desperately need a workaround.

Is there any workaround, maybe by using SVG instead?